# Build Dynamic Image Gallery Jquery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Im trying to build this gallery:

[image]

How would I go about building this image gallery using jquery, and having the thumbnails populate automatically based on how many images I had in a folder? Id like to click the thumbnail and have it open a new page or div with a bigger image.

Id also like to make each thumbnail fade in 1 after the other.

Comment: Do you want a conceptual overview of each subtask required to do this from start to finish, or do you want actual code?

Comment: im not a coder... im just a designer whos trying to be more than quite an honest. I try to learn the code as i get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer pertains to only the HTML/CSS/jQuery part of your question.

If you want to show images in a folder instead of mini Google logos, you will need some simple server side code written in a language such as PHP or ASP.NET. If you are using PHP, I can write this for you.

---

I've tested this in IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome.

I've kept it as simple as I could while trying to keep the details you asked for:

***[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/eyozo4)***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Demo Gallery</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0
}
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #eee;
    width: 377px;
    height: 355px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
#container img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left; margin: 5px 0 0 5px
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //fill container with test images
    $('#container').append(new Array(60).join('<a href="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" width="64" height="64" /></a>'))

    var $images = $('#container img');

    $images.hide();

    $images.each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(index * 50).fadeIn();
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" width="64" height="64" /></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

In response to your comments: ***[Live Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/eyozo4/2/)***

- I made all the "non-selected images" have 50% opacity.
- When you hover over an image, it gets 100% opacity.
- Visited images have a purple border instead of red.

Comment: @thirtydot: you've provided exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks alot. One small mod i just thought of if i may ask... what if i wanted to gray out all the non-selected images? and how could I apply hover and visited states to these images? I will try my best to see if i can write this mod myself in the meantime, even though ive not the strongest of confidence ill be able to pull it off. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @WillingLearner: I made some changes.

Comment: @thirtydot: thanks for the edit.  I tried to edit your code, in order to select a bunch of different images from a folder named thumbs, but it seems to fail for some reason, and I quite figure why. Im trying to append the .jpg extension as seeing the code you have already names the images 1,2, etc. This is what I tried: 

//fill container with test images
    for (var i=1; i<400; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<a href="thumbs/'+i+'" target="_blank"><img src="thumbs/'+.jpg'" width="35" height="35" style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-left: 4px; padding: 0px"/></a>')
  }

why dosent it work?

Comment: @WillingLearner: That code was just for testing but whatever, here you go: `for (var i=1; i<400; i++) { $('#container').append('<a href="thumbs/'+i+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="thumbs/'+i+'.jpg" width="35" height="35" style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-left: 4px; padding: 0px"/></a>') }`

Comment: @thirtydot: I got the syntax wrong i see. Thanks for correcting me.  I have 1 final question and then ill be moving on to the rest of my application and will be done taking up your valuable time on this question as you've helped me so much already: why doesn't "target="#mydiv" work? Im now trying to load my image into another div instead of new page(_blank). Im baffled as to why this fails to work when i try it to be quite honest.

Comment: @WillingLearner: That simply won't work. You should use something like [Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) instead.

Comment: @thirtydot: Quick question...if i wanted to make my faded thumbnails have a gray color overlay over them, how would i do that? I tried:
//$(this).css('background-color','#333333'); it dosent quite seem to give me the effect I want though... i want the faded image to look gray, not the background behind it.

Comment: If you mean you want the images to be fully desaturated (greyscale), then I don't think it's possible with CSS/JS/jQuery. You would have to create grey images manually, or you can [use PHP to make greyscale](http://bubble.ro/How_to_convert_an_image_to_grayscale_using_PHP.html) versions of your images. The ideal solution would be to combine the greyscale version of your thumbnail with the normal version in one image, then `.css()` the `background-position`, this technique is called "CSS Sprites". See [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-sprites). You should make a new question if you need ++help.